# Bajar archivos de BD mysql

Tags: php, php7

Estoy tratando de bajar un archivo que subo a la BD por codigo, y eso me funciona perfectamente, pero ahora estoy intentado bajarlo y no he podido.

El codigo que tengo hasta ahora es este:

```html
<?php
 require_once "conexion.php";
 $id = ($_GET['id']);
 $sql = "SELECT nombre, tipo, contenido FROM archivos WHERE codigo_archivo = $id";
 echo $sql;
 $dwn = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
 $type = mysql_result($dwn, 0, 'tipo');
 $contenido = mysql_result($dwn, 0, 'contenido');
 header("Content-type: $type");
 print $contenido;
 ?>
```

Se que mysql_result ya está obsoleto, pero esto es lo que encontrado en internet pero no me esta funcionando, me aparecen los siguientes errores:

Warning:  mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in on line 7

Warning:  mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in on line 8

y la verdad no se mucho de este tema, agradeceria mucho la ayuda que me puedan dar

Comment: Bueno la primer observación que yo te haría es que: estás mezclando el uso de APIs es decir por un lado empleas *mysqli* y luego usas *mysql* la cual esta obsoleta y removida desde PHP 7

Comment: Si @BetaM, por eso dije que mysql ya esta obsoleta, pero es lo que he encntrado en internet hasta ahora y no se mucho sobre este tema, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dejo la solución a la respuesta formulada por mi:

```html
if($_GET){
  $id = "";
  $contenido = "";
  $tipo = "";
  require_once "conexion.php";
  $id = ($_GET['id']);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM archivos WHERE codigo_archivo = $id";
  $dwn = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  var_dump ($dwn);
  if(mysqli_affected_rows($db)){
   $file = mysqli_fetch_array($dwn);
   $nombre = $file['nombre'];
   $type = $file['tipo'];
   $size = filesize($file['nombre']);
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   header("Content-type: $type", true);
   header("Content-Type: application/forced-download");
   header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$nombre");
   header("Content-Length: $size");
   readfile ($contenido);
  } else {
   //Escribir error y redireccionar a crear-activicades.php
  }
 }
```

Esta solución fue posible gracias a un amigo que me ayudó a resolver mi duda, la dejo por si alguien tiene  el mismo problema sepa como resolver este inconveniente.
Gracias a todos